# Arduino code won't upload with Ethernet Shield attached

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide

I've been playing with my [Arduino Boards](https://www.sabdel.com/shop/electronics/5v-4-channel-relay-shield-expansion-board-for-arduino/) for a while. I have an [Arduino Nano](https://www.sabdel.com/shop/electronics/328p-multifunction-expansion-board-v3-0-for-arduino-nano-uno/) and a Duemilanove 328.

I've been able to program both of them without problems for weeks. Any example project I try will compile and upload with no issue.

I recently got an Ethernet shield... I'm trying some test sketches and no matter which board I try, with the shield attached I get:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
```

As I said, without the Ethernet shield attached all is bliss....

Do I have a bad shield or am I just doing something stupid?

Comment: I don't know how it works but Go to the Device manager and Assign a different COM port to your Arduino over there! It worked for me :D

Answer (score 1):

The Ethernet Shield uses the pins  D10, D11, D12 and D13 on the Arduino UNO. I presume there is a conflict and you use one or more of these digital pins in your setup already.

A nice overview of possible conflicts between shields and arduino boards can be found at: 
http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ShieldPinUsage